# bind() error : Cannot assign requested address

Tags: c, sockets, udp, port, bind

> bind () error : Cannot assign requested address.

```
new_socket= socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
       
    localIP = "128.1.1.64";

    memset(&socket_data, 0, sizeof(socket_data));
    
    // Fill the socket structure
    socket_data.sin_family      = AF_INET;
    socket_data.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(localIP);
    socket_data.sin_port        = htons(PortNumber);
bind( new_socket, (struct sockaddr*) &socket_data, sizeof(socket_data))
```

Does any one know why the `bind()` is failing?

Comment: Bind to 0.0.0.0.

Comment: Is `128.1.1.64` the IP address of one of your computer's local network interfaces?  If not, then trying to `bind()` to it won't work.

Comment: by default, the only loopback address that gets created is `127.0.0.1`.  If you want to create more, you can (with `ifconfig` on linux, other systems are different), but you'd need to do that for your odd loopback address before you can bind to it.

Answer (score 2):

I guess 128.1.1.64 is an arbitrary IP which does not exist in any of your net interfaces. If you want to spoof the source IP, probably you need to use `SOCK_RAW` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can only `bind()` to an IP that has been assigned to one of the network interfaces of the local machine.